# ¿Cómo obtener el último elemento que no sea cero en un arreglo?

Tags: python, array, openerp

Tengo una función que busca un id y lo compara con otro, después de eso busca ese id en una lista, sin embargo, a veces el **último** & **penúltimo** **registro** podrían ser **cero**, por lo que quisiera obtener el último registro que no esté en cero

A continuación les dejo la función:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('seller_ids')
def _costo_anterior(self):
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if self.default_code or self.default_code !='':
        product_search = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=',self.default_code)],limit = 1) 
        all_seller_ids = product_search.seller_ids.ids
        _logger.info('seller_ids: %s', all_seller_ids)

        if  all_seller_ids:
            id_ultimo_costo =  all_seller_ids[-1]
            supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
            self.costo_anterior = supplier.price
            _logger.info('Costo anterior: %s', self.costo_anterior)

            if self.costo_anterior == 0.0 and len(all_seller_ids) > 1:
                id_ultimo_costo = all_seller_ids[-2]
                supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)])
                self.costo_anterior = supplier.price
            else:
                _logger.info('Solo tiene un registro')
        else:
            self.costo_anterior = 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una función como esta:

```
def ultimo_no_cero(lista):
    valor = 0
    for valor in lista[::-1]:
        if valor:
            break
    return valor
```

que retorna el último elemento no cero de la lista, o cero si la lista está vacia o no tiene valores distintos.

El truco está en recorrer la lista en orden inverso, lo que se logra con `lista[::-1]`, que la invierte.

Luego es cosa de retornar con el primer valor no cero.

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
]

def ultimo_no_cero(lista):
    valor = 0
    for valor in lista[::-1]:
        if valor:
            break
    return valor


for test in tests:
    print(test, ultimo_no_cero(test))
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3] 3
[0, 1, 2, 3] 3
[1, 2, 3, 0] 3
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0] 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Por `lista[::-1]` también se puede usar `reversed(lista)`, el cual [pasa un objeto iterador](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) que no hace copias de la lista original, y ocupa menos memoria.

Comment: Funciona perfecto! & también la solución de @aeportugal muchas gracias!